# I want to Google for two patterns in the domain name, how?

Tags: google-search

I'm trying to search for websites that are still using "http" and have in their name: "keyserver". How to do this?

So far I tried this:

"inurl:http" "inurl:keyserver"

But it shows hits with `http://foo.com/bar/keyserver`.

I only want to search in `http://foo.com`!

Answer (score 2):

Search in sites that has in the URL `http` and in the title `keyserver`

```
inurl:http intitle:keyserver
```

Sites that has in the URL `http` and in the title `keyserver` or phrase `"key server"`

```
inurl:http intitle:(keyserver OR "key server")
```

Use `site` operator to narrow down the results by particular domain

```
inurl:http intitle:keyserver site:example.com
```

---

Note: using `inurl:http` will include results that have string `http` anywhere in the URL, e.g. `https://example.com/wiki/http`